# Other options than setting IEnumerable to optional

Tags: c#, linq

From what I have read `IEnumerable` cannot be set to optional. I have a method `public IEnumerable<StatusInt> StatusInts { get; set; }` that always passes in the default of 0 if the user does not select an option from a combo box.  For simple data types I can just add ? and the parameter becomes optional and null is passed in.  Is there anything similar that I can do with `IEnumerable`

Comment: "Cannot be set to optional" in what sense? `IEnumerable<T>` is just another reference type - you can use an optional parameter with a default value of null perfectly easily...

Comment: Regardless of nullability, `IEnumerable<T>` can be an empty collection, so if you're receiving a value in the collection when nothing is selected, something is broken in your front-end code.

Comment: Can you provide a link to what you've read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value types can be set to optional with the `?` character.

`int?`' is just short for `Nullable<int>`

`IEnumerable` is not a value type, it's a reference type. Reference types are already optional - you can return `null` if you want.

```
IEnumerable<StatusInt> StatusInts
{
   get
   {
       if(this.OptionIsSelected)
       {
           return GenerateOptions(this.Option);
       }
       else 
       {
            return null;
       }
   }
}
```

However, I recommend you don't do this. Instead, return an empty enumerable. This way your calling code does not need to check for a `null` value. You are less likely to inadvertently trigger a null reference exception.

```
IEnumerable<StatusInt> StatusInts
{
   get
   {
       if(this.OptionIsSelected)
       {
           return GenerateOptions(this.Option);
       }
       else 
       {
            return Enumerable.Empty<StatusInt>();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You've used the term "optional" here when I think you should be using "nullable."  Optional parameters are entirely different than nullable value types.

Comment: @BJMyers - In this case, I was deliberately using the word 'optional' because that was the word the questioner was using. 
When I'm answering questions to a beginner, I have to appreciate there are hurdles in understanding basic concepts. Talking to them using the language they've adopted assists in getting them across these initial hurdles, and closer to the point where we can address finer points of nomenclature.